# Eloquent how to build query to sum totals subqueries inside from?

Tags: php, database, eloquent, subquery, union

I have already built the MySql query statements in which have the results i needed, below the small example closed to real situation:

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT  
        Total,
        SUM(Hours)
        SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
        SUM(Paid) AS Paid
FROM    (   SELECT  
                    Total AS Total,
                    SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
                    SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
                    NULL AS Paid
            FROM    Table
            WHERE   type = 'regular'
            GROUP BY id
            UNION
            SELECT  
                    Total AS Total,
                    SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
                    SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
                    NULL AS Paid
            FROM    Table
            WHERE   type = 'credit'
            GROUP BY id
            UNION
            SELECT  
                    Total AS Total,
                    SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
                    SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
                    NULL AS Paid
            FROM    Table
            WHERE   type = 'tax'
            GROUP BY id
        ) t
GROUP BY Total;
```

Here is the ORM query so far created in which i accomplish to get the results from the union, but still missing to insert the '$all" query inside the from.

Made 2 subquery, on the 3rd query added the union, so fare it work's, but still can not figure out, how to create the initial select statement to merge all subqueries inside from.

**ELOQUENT**

```
$credit = DB::table('table')
->selectRaw('
          Total AS Total,
          SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
          SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
          NULL AS Paid
')
->where('type', '=', 'credit')
->groupBy('id');

$tax = DB::table('table')
->selectRaw('
          Total AS Total,
          SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
          SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
          NULL AS Paid
')
->where('type', '=', 'tax')
->groupBy('id');

$all = DB::table('table')
->selectRaw('
          Total AS Total,
          SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
          SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
          NULL AS Paid
')
->where('type', '=', 'regular')
->groupBy('id')
->union($credit)
->union($tax);

$totals = DB::selectRaw('
              Total,
              SUM(Hours),
              SUM(Charge),
              Paid
          ')
          ->from( $all->toSql() )
          ->groupBy('Total')
          ->get();
```

Any help will be great to figure this out!.

Answer (score 0):

After reading and getting a better understanding of the Eloquent query builder helper class, figure the answer to my question.

Since the query builder is using PDO in the background, we know there is a way to bind parameters to our query so it will sanitize the bound variables.

Now, as you've seen, arbitrary (raw) queries are done in the query builder using the DB::select() method. Let's look at the select() method in Illuminate\Database\Connection to see if it has any way to bind our parameters:

```
public function select($query, $bindings = array())
{
    return $this->run($query, $bindings, function($me, $query, $bindings)
    {
        if ($me->pretending()) return array();

        // For select statements, we'll simply execute the query and return an array
        // of the database result set. Each element in the array will be a single
        // row from the database table, and will either be an array or objects.
        $statement = $me->getPdo()->prepare($query);

        $statement->execute($me->prepareBindings($bindings));

        return $statement->fetchAll($me->getFetchMode());
    });
}
```

Made some adjustments to my initial query, the DB:select takes as second parameter the bindings which got from sub-query the $all->getBindings() to parse then issued was resolved.

**SOLUTION:**

```
$credit = DB::table('table')
->selectRaw('
          Total AS Total,
          SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
          SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
          NULL AS Paid
')
->whereRaw('type = ? ', ['credit'])
->groupBy('id');

$tax = DB::table('table')
->selectRaw('
          Total AS Total,
          SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
          SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
          NULL AS Paid
')
->whereRaw('type = ? ', ['tax'])
->groupBy('id');

$all = DB::table('table')
->selectRaw('
          Total AS Total,
          SUM(Hours) AS Hours,
          SUM(Charge) AS Charge,
          NULL AS Paid
')
->whereRaw('type = ? ', ['regular'])
->groupBy('id')
->union($credit)
->union($tax);

$totals = DB::select("SELECT
              Total,
              SUM(Hours),
              SUM(Charge),
              Paid
              FROM ({$all->toSql()}) AS t
          ", $all->getBindings())
          ->groupBy('Total')
          ->get();
```

Just hope this help someone with the same problem. Thanks! :).